# Chef knife winRM interactive mode hangs in Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, chef-infra, winrm

I've been stuck on this issue for the past 3 or 4 days.  I am trying to run the attached command  in a Windows batch file in Jenkins.  This causes it to hang and it doesn't accept any further inputs:

```
knife winrm ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com interactive -m -x Administrator -P xxxxxxxx
```

This works fine if run manually on a Windows machine, but I think the ruby.exe that is being opened is starting to cause Jenkins some problems.

Has anyone ever used knife winRM's interactive mode in such a way before?  I'm at my wits end here and I really need this to work.  Thank you for any help you could provide.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it as "call knife" instead of just "knife"? If, inside a batch file, you run another batch file (knife.bat, for example) without "call", the initial batch file run is terminated. There's a good explanation here: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php

Comment: Yep, tried this and I still get the same issue.  It will run the first knife command but if i have a second command in the same batch file, the second command is never run.

Comment: If the two knife commands are in separate "Execute Windows batch command" boxes, does that work?